# Struggling with the syntax for unpacking a nested property through destructuring and placing it as an argument for a function

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with the syntax for unpacking a nested value/property and placing it as an argument/parameter in a function.

In the 2nd code-snippet, I want `hiding` to return `1`.

Based on the success of this:

```js
o = {
color: "red", 
nested: {num: 5}
}

function f({color, nested: {num: number}}) { 
console.log(color);
console.log(number);
}

f(o)
```

I'm wondering why `1` isn't assigned to the variable `hiding`.

```js
o = {
    color: "red", 
    nested: {num: 5},
    doubleNested: {
       property: {
          hidden: 1
       }
    }
}
    
function f({color, nested: {num: number}}, doubleNested: property: {hidden: hiding}}) { 
console.log(color);
console.log(number);
console.log(hiding);
}

f(o);
```

Comment: You have braces missing in the parameter: `doubleNested: { property: {`...etc

Comment: There's a typo with your brackets. It should be: `{color, nested: {num: number}, doubleNested:{ property: {hidden: hiding}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct variant, it was just a type with brackets + missing the second argument.

```js
const o = {
    color: "red", 
    nested: {num: 5},
    doubleNested: {
       property: {
          hidden: 1
       }
    }
}

function f({ color, nested: { num: number } }, { doubleNested: { property: { hidden: hiding } } }) {
    console.log(color);
    console.log(number);
    console.log(hiding);
}

f(o, o)
```

Comment: Why passing the same variable as argument instead of moving a bracket to the end?